# Proxy error: Could not proxy request ... from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/

Tags: node.js, reactjs

How to fix the error below?
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/auth/register from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000/.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z73hs.png) See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Run backend and this error will be removed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You must have set `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000/"` in your package.json in your client side.
What this does is that it prefixes every request with the proxy.

So this problem will arise if your backend server is listening at port other than 5000(since your every request will be directed at `http://localhost:5000/<api>`)

SOLUTION:

**either** change the proxy to what your backend server is listening at
**or**
change the backend server's listening port to what the proxy is set at.